# Open a csv file in DOS

Tags: csv, dos, batch-file

Is it possible to open a csv file such as:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
```

And have DOS read it in (in a batch file), check the data and then remove it from the file under a certain condition?

Pseudo code:

```
open csv file
for each letter
    if letter is e
        remove e from csv file
close and save csv file
```

EDIT:

If I change my data source from a csv to this:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

Then I can call this:

```
rename file.txt file.bak
        for /f %%a in (file.bak) do (
            set hmm=%%a
            if !hmm!==e set hmm=helloworld
            echo !hmm! >> file.txt)
```

Although this will print out the original data after the new changes like so:

```
a
b
c
d
helloworld
f
g
h
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

Comment: Batch files are a poor fit for this. Consider a richer language (or a spreadsheet - DOS-based ones do exist). Also, is it really DOS, or just a command line in Windows?

Comment: I'm planning on running it through a batch file. I was thinking of using VBScript, but after I have my data (in the example above, the letter 'e') I then need to call a dos command with the data as a parameter.

Comment: @Seva: On this site I have seen maybe one or two actual DOS questions. All data points to the fact that most people who say DOS just mean "the weird gray on black stuff you never use on Windows" – i.e. the Windows Command Processor, cmd. I've given up educating people about the differences by now. It's just too saddening ;-). That being said, simple CSV files can easily be parsed with `for /f` nearly without problems.

Comment: If it's indeed Windows command line, Windows Scripting Host (JS/VBS) in conjuction with the FileSystem/TextStream objects is the answer. All the parsing is done by means of ReadLine() and String.split().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my fix:

```
rename file.txt file.bak
        for /f %%a in (file.bak) do (
            set hmm=%%a
            if !hmm!==e set hmm=helloworld
            echo !hmm! >> file.txt)
del file.bak
```

If you don't delete the bak file it will print both the txt and bak into the new file! Weird!

Answer (score 1):

With `FOR /F`, you can go through a text file and process the content of each column (called tokens), where you can choose what character is separating the columns.

In order to remove it from the file, I guess you'd have to recreate a new file where you decide what to write and what to not write.

Comment: I've seen some examples of `FOR /F` I'll do a bit of experimentation and report back!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the tokens using for /f and use
set str=%str:e=%
to remove the tokens you don't want and then use ">" to indirect it to another file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example in Windows PowerShell 2:

```
$split = Get-Content "C:\temp\test.csv" | ForEach-Object {$_.Split(",") | Where-Object {$_ -ne "e"} }
[string]::join(",", $split) | Out-File -Encoding ASCII "C:\temp\testOUT.csv"
```

This will work on the base case (a single line). It has problems with a multi-line CSV; perhaps someone with more PS-fu than I can fix it.

I did not test this with boundary conditions (empty file, blank line, line consisting of a single letter, adjacent commas, line of all e's, etc.).

For CSV files with column headers, PowerShell provides the [Import-Csv cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx) (as well as Export-Csv).